# configuration of logwatch: remove from "known attacks" & "probed the server"

Tags: logwatch

I rely on logwatch to get infos about my production servers.
Unfortunately two sections provide to much information:

```
 Attempts to use known hacks by 656 hosts were logged 1796 time(s)
 from:
     xxx.xxx.xxx.xx: 39 Time(s)
        /\.\./\.\./\.\./ 39 Time(s)
     xx.x.x.x.x: 24 Time(s)
        ^null$ 24 Time(s)
     x.x.x.x.x: 16 Time(s)
        ^null$ 16 Time(s)
```

How can I remove the entries that shown me a ^null$ attack? I have hundreds of them and will not follow up on them anyway.

I also want to remove the list of 656 IPs that follow this entry:

```
A total of 656 sites probed the server
```

Can you point me to a solution?

Answer (score 1):

I had this same issue with my Ubuntu system. The logwatch reports were way too long and these two sections were especially bad. After looking around for a configuration change and not finding anything I decided to delve into the program itself. It is written in PERL and the relevant file is /usr/share/logwatch/scripts/services/http
Search for the strings "known hacks" and "probed the server" and simply comment out those sections of the code. Worked like a charm for me.

Comment: Remember that you'll have to do this again whenever logwatch is updated. This should be considered as a workaround at best.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Thomas answer, you can modify `/usr/share/logwatch/scripts/services/http` and comment the "probed the server" section, but if you comment the "known hacks" section you will be missing other types of hacks rather than only "^null$".

What I did was add the string `.\^null\$.` to `/etc/logwatch/conf/ignore.conf`.

This way, other types of hacks is still showing in the report, like `passwd$` and `win\.ini`